# Is there any message in Monero's genesis block like there is in Bitcoin's?

Tags: blockchain, genesisblock

As the title says, what data was used to seed Monero's genesis block?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

None afaik, Monero (then Bitmonero) was launched as a fork of Bytecoin. Not thats impossible as the Bytecoin blockchain is full of messages and cryptic data:

http://bytecoiner.org/bytecoin-early-adopters-and-secret-messages

https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=512747.msg7126913#msg7126913

obs: there is large suspicion that the bytecoin blockchain was faked: https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=740112.0